# Are $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A box has six balls numbered from one to six. The balls numbered $1$ and $2$ are red while the remaining balls are white. Two balls are drawn at random from the box (without replacement and without order), let $X$ and $Y$ be the random variables representing the number of red balls and the number of even balls in the sample, respectively. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables?

My intuition tells me that they are not independent. But I don't know how to progress with this problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexhange. If $X = 2$, can you say anything about $Y$? If you can, the random variables are not independent. *This would be different if you draw with replacement, so in that case ...*

Comment: Please explain your intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of pairs can be "6 choose 2", $\binom{6}{2}$ and the number of pairs when one of the balls is red and the other is even are 5:

$$ {(1,2), (1,4), (1,6), (2,4), (2,6)}.$$ Note $(2,2)$ is not included in the set since you are choosing without replacement. The probability of the event then is $5/15=1/3$ which is not the same as the probability of choosing red and even: $$P(X)P(Y)=(2/6)(3/6).$$ Therefore, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, $X$ has values $(0, 1, 2)$ with $P(X=0)=2/5$, $P(X=1)=8/15$ and $P(X=2)=1/15$.  For $Y$, $P(Y=2)=P(Y=0)=1/5$, while $P(Y=1)=3/5$.

$X$ and $Y$ are not independent. (for example) $P((X=2)\cap (Y=1))=1/15$
$\ne P(X=2) P(Y=1)=5/75$, since both red balls must be of opposite color.